1054: Unknown column 'CLIENT_REF' in 'where clause'
Мучаюсь с этим уже 2-й день, и что-то процесс с места не двигается. Пытаюсь внести данные в таблицу:
INSERT INTO `mybank`.`ACCOUNTS` (`ID`, `NAME`, `SALDO`, `CLIENT_REF`, `OPEN_DATE`, `PRODUCT_REF`, `ACC_NUM`) VALUES (4, 'Кредитный счет для Кузнецова Д.И.', -7000.00, 4, '2019-03-10', 4, '45502810401020000040');
INSERT INTO `mybank`.`ACCOUNTS` (`ID`, `NAME`, `SALDO`, `CLIENT_REF`, `OPEN_DATE`, `PRODUCT_REF`, `ACC_NUM`) VALUES (5, 'Депозитный счет для Смирновой О.П.', 7000.00, 5, '2019-05-12', 5, '42301810400000000005');
INSERT INTO `mybank`.`ACCOUNTS` (`ID`, `NAME`, `SALDO`, `CLIENT_REF`, `OPEN_DATE`, `PRODUCT_REF`, `ACC_NUM`) VALUES (6, 'Карточный счет для Ивановой Е.В.', 17000.00, 6, '2019-07-15', 6, '40817810700000000005');

В результате данного запроса SQL возвращает мне следующее:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'CLIENT_REF' in 'where clause'
С чем может быть связана данная ошибка, если в таблице имеется поле CLIENT_REF?


Вашу проблему трудно воспроизвести при отсутствии структуры таблиц. Не дополните свой код?

Да, конечно, уже добавил

Диаграмма к месту, но вообще отлично было бы с кодом. На будущее: "Как задать хороший вопрос": https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Числовые значение не нужно писать в кавычках. Попробуйте их убрать

Числовые без кавычек, просто когда копируешь код из mysql workbench они почему-то вставляются.

Проблема явно не в них, sql по какой-то причине не находит столбец с CLIENT_REF

Один из вариантов - какой то символ написан в русской раскладке. Попробуйте что то выбрать из таблицы, указав where CLIENT_REF = 'что то'. Попробуйте скопировать название столбца и вставить в запрос

Проверено, все символы в английской раскладке и капсом, помимо этого запрос возвращает нужные данные

Сообщение об ошибке однозначно указывает, что проблемное поле найдено в кляузе WHERE. Однако запрос INSERT не содержит такой кляузы. Вывод однозначен - имеется триггер, в котором и происходит ошибка.

Понял, в чём у вас ошибка — вы не указали столбец CLOSE_DATE при вставке в таблицу ACCOUNTS. Ваша таблица состоит из 8 полей, а в запросе вы вставляете только 7.

Да, вы верно заметили, тут действительно ошибка, но исправив её, проблема почему-то не решилась

То же самое сообщение выводит? То есть вывод данных у вас корректен, но вы никак не можете внести данные?

Да, всё верно, продолжает ругаться на столбец 'CLIENT_REF', может ли быть причина в том что это ключ к таблице CLIENTS? Если это так, то всё равно не понятно, так как в CLIENTS уже существуют такие пользователи.

У вас ID в таблице Clients автоинкрементный? Вы не добавляли пользователей с такими ID ранее? Сколько у вас записей в Clients?

Добавил в Client пользователей только один раз, буквально перед вставкой в ACCOUNTS. Сам ID автоинкрементный.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что: 1) В таблице Clients есть записи с ID 4, 5 и 6? 2) Что поле ID в Accounts тоже автоинкрементое? 3) Что вы уже добавляли записи, описанные в вопросе, но затем удалили их из таблицы Accounts?


Да, всё верно, записи все есть
Все поля ID во всех таблицах автоинкрементны
Нет, в Accounts ничего из текущего кода не добавлялось, там уже содержались 3 другие записи, которые были добавлены ранее.


Когда вы вставляли 3 предыдущие записи в Accounts, было 7 или 8 аргументов? Каким образом вам удалось вставить те предыдущие записи? Что могло измениться?

Предыдущие записи вставлял точно таким же способом, все аргументы были на месте, всё работало, потом вышел из mysql workbench и началось это.

К сожалению, тогда мои полномочия на этом кончаются ¯_(ツ)_/¯ . Похоже, что ваша проблема не воспроизводима... Дальше я знаю только то, что и обычный пользователь: попробуйте перезайти, перезагрузить mysql (в критических моментах иногда помогает перезагрузка ПК). На крайний случай просто пересоздайте БД (если мало записей) или отдельные таблицы. Проверьте также подключение к БД (оно может слететь, а проблема вскроется не сразу). Удачи вам в решении вашей проблемы!

Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — из очереди проверок

@ksa, с удовольствием бы удалил свой ответ, но тогда пропадут и комментарии к нему. Вот если бы их можно было перенести в вопрос. Но тогда получится дискуссия. По-хорошему вопрос нужно закрыть, поскольку мы с автором выяснили, что проблема невоспроизводима
